# Convex envelop of Tr(XY)?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

How would one go about calculating the convex envelop of $f(X,Y) = Tr(XY)$, where both $X \in R^{ n \times n}$ and $Y \in R^{ n \times n}$ define the domain of $f$ and are both symmetric PSD? I am trying to calculate a global under-estimator of $f$.

Comment: I would start with the low-dimensional cases.  $n=1$ we can do "by inspection" and $n=2$ should be tractable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's well known that $\mbox{tr}(XY) \geq 0$ for all PSD pairs $(X,Y)$.  Unfortunately, you can't do any better than that in finding the convex envelope.  Let $g(X,Y)$ be the convex envelope of $f(X,Y)$.  I claim that $g(X,Y)=0$.

Take any pair $(X,Y)$ in the domain of $f$.  The pairs $(2X,0)$ and $(0,2Y)$ are also in the domain of $f$.

$f(2X,0)=0$

$f(0,2Y)=0$

$f(X,Y)=f((2X,0)/2+(0,2Y)/2)$

Thus $g(X,Y) \leq 0$.

Comment: Very nice @Brian! So the indicator of the Cartesian product PSD $\times$ PSD is the convex envelope.

Comment: that was awesome!

Comment: Thanks @Brian Borchers for the helpful assist.